commitizen - how to run commit check in gitlab ci
I'm using a commitizen and a pre-commit
- repo: https://github.com/commitizen-tools/commitizen
  rev: v3.27.0
  hooks:
    - id: commitizen
      name: commit message check

On local everything is working perfect - commitizen is triggered by pre-commit and the commit message is validated. The thing is that when I create a Merge Request I'm running a pipeline in gitlab ci with pre-commit run --all-files --show-diff-on-failure to make sure that the code which is supposed to be merged meets all the requirements. The thing is that all hooks are triggered except commitizen.
So the question is - how can I check if commits which will be added by MR follow the commitizen format ?
How to run commitizen hook witg pre-commit run ?

your command works great for pre-commit / pre-push style hooks -- but commitizen is a commit-msg hook so you have to adjust the command (and approach) significantly
first you sort of have to understand how pre-commit calls commit-msg hooks in the first place.  git places a file on disk (usually .git/COMMIT_MSG) and then pre-commit passes that filename along to tools.
in order to replicate that in CI, you need to write out files for each commit message you want to test, and then run each of those through pre-commit with a command similar to:
# assume you wrote the commit messages into this directory
find commit-msgs -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} pre-commit run --commit-msg-filename {} --hook-stage commit-msg


disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit
